# Create a new branch and discard local commits on the other

Tags: git

Currently there are 2 remote branches: `master` and `development`. How we work (and how most people work) is that you create a branch for a feature.

Now, I did everything in `development`. I just created a new branch for my feature which - and this makes sense - is up to date with my local branch (because I created it from my local `development` branch).

Is it possible to discard the commits in branch `development` but still keep them in my newly created branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just do `git branch -f development origin/development` to repoint the local `development` branch to the remote `development` branch.

Comment: And the commits will still be in my newly created branch, so that if I merge my new branch with development the changes get there?

Comment: Of course. A branch is just a post-it note that sticks on a commit. Peeling off the `development` post-it note and sticking it to another commit does not influence in any way the other post-it notes you have in your repo.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, I'm not that experienced with Git and I don't want to cause massive destruction in the repository. All jokes aside, thanks for the answer. Cheers!

Comment: There are very few commands in Git with which you really loose data or that cannot be undone easily.